# $http in Ionic app not catching errors

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, ionic-framework, genymotion

I'm running an Ionic Android app under Genymotion emulator.

I'm having a problem with $http. When the request is successful then it's all fine.
However when the request would return with a 401/403/404 code, an exception is thrown in Ionic framework: `ionic.bundle.js` line 17288:

> "Cannot read property 'data' of undefined", response is undefined.

It seems like Ionic intercepts the responses, and 401/403/404 errors still tries to trigger the .success() callback. See attached excerpt from `ionic.bundle.js`:

[image]

Ionic Version: `1.0.0-rc.0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused because I had an HTTP interceptor in my app.js. It seemed harmless but commenting it out solved the problem. Seem below what got commented out:

```
//  .config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
//    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function() {
//      return {
//        'responseError': function(rejection) {
//          var message = "HTTP Error " + rejection.statusText + "(" + rejection.status + ") on " + rejection.config.method + " " + rejection.config.url;
//
//          if (typeof rejection.data !== 'undefined')
//            message += " Error response: " + JSON.stringify(rejection.data);
//
//          // same as above
//          if (typeof _errs !== 'undefined')
//            _errs.push(new Error(message));
//          else
//            console.log(message);
//        }
//      };
//    });
//  }])
```